# Error in NodeJS when using express session with Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, redis

I have a project in Node.js where I used MemoryStore from express-session, but when I changed to use the session with redis (connect-redis) I receive the error **ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command** when accessing any page and cannot log in (because the session is not created, or is created incorrectly).

Trying to find why this is happening I created a simple project to see what is causing the error, but even after a lot of search I could not find the reason. I followed the instructions in https://github.com/tj/connect-redis and saw a lot of examples here in https://stackoverflow.com/ but the error is still happening. I tested in more ways (commented lines and others), but it's still happening. It only occurs when acessing a page (`localhost:3000`, there's only this page in this test), not on the server start.

---

The `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "express-load": "^1.1.15",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "redis": "^2.4.2",
    "connect-redis": "^3.0.2",
    "ejs": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

The `app.js` file:

```js
const SECRET = 'test';

var express = require('express')
  , load = require('express-load')
  , expressSession = require('express-session')
  , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
  , cookie = cookieParser(SECRET)
  //, cookie = cookieParser()
  , redis = require('redis')
  , RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(expressSession)
  //, redisClient = redis.createClient()
  , redisClient = redis.createClient({host: '127.0.0.1', port: '6379'})
  , store = new RedisStore({client: redisClient})
  //, store = new RedisStore({host: '127.0.0.1', port: '6379'})
  //, store = new expressSession.MemoryStore()
  , session = expressSession({
      store: store,
      secret: SECRET, 
      resave: true, 
      saveUninitialized: true
    })
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').Server(app)
;

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cookie);
app.use(session);

load('controllers')
  .then('routes')
  .into(app)
;

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Testing...');
});
```

If I comment `, store = new RedisStore({client: redisClient})` and uncomment `, store = new expressSession.MemoryStore()`, I don't receive the error and it works fine with sessions. This test project is very simple and I find it weird that the error still happens, when I do the same thing like many other examples that I saw.

This test project - aside from the node_modules - only has 1 page `/views/home/index.ejs`, 1 controller `/controllers/home.js` and 1 route `/routes/home.js`, but they are very simple and the only thing they do is lead the user to the simple page `/views/home/index.ejs`, so the error must not be in one of those.

---

**Edit**

The error stack trace:

```
[path]\test>npm start

> test@0.0.1 start [path]\test
> node app.js

Testing...
Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    at JavascriptReplyParser._parseResult ([path]\test\node_modules\redis\lib\parsers\javascript.js:43:16)
    at JavascriptReplyParser.try_parsing ([path]\test\node_modules\redis\lib\parsers\javascript.js:114:21)
    at JavascriptReplyParser.run ([path]\test\node_modules\redis\lib\parsers\javascript.js:126:22)
    at JavascriptReplyParser.execute ([path]\test\node_modules\redis\lib\parsers\javascript.js:107:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> ([path]\test\node_modules\redis\index.js:131:27)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your version of Redis server.

https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/372

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I fixed the problem. The redis I was using was in version 2.5.3, and it seems fine. But for some reason there was no directory \connect-redis\node_modules\redis, so I don't know if the connect-redis was trying to take an older global version of redis or something like that, but the problem was probably the version of redis used by connect-redis (in the package.json of connect-redis, there is "redis": "^2.1.0", so maybe it was trying to use an out of date redis?). I just removed and installed connect-redis again and it has now the redis directory in version 2.5.3.